# TERM environment variable not set

Tags: python, консоль, python-3.6

Написал простой код на python3.6:

```py
import os
def cls():
    os.system('cls' if os.name=='nt' else 'clear')
print('Delete this')
cls()
```

выдает ошибку:

> TERM environment variable not set. Как исправить?

Comment: Можно пожалуйста полный текст ошибки?

Comment: TERM environment variable not set

Comment: Больше ничего нет

Answer (score 1):

Текст ошибки ясно говорит ,что делайте.
Запускайте вашу прогу в терминале(cmd,iterm2,konsole, что угодно...).